# Welcome Message (Embed)

Tags: discord, discord.js

This is my code:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.guild.channels.get('605000838573850635').send("Welcome *" + member + "* on the server!"); 
});
```

It should look like the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p4fD.png

Comment: and what's the problem?

Comment: I want an embedded welcome message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are embedded messages, you can send them like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('Welcome')
        .addField('', member.nickname)
        .setImage(member.user.avatarURL)

    member.guild.channels.get('605000838573850635').send(exampleEmbed);
})
```